# Exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' was thrown. Parameter name: encodedValue

Tags: sharepoint-2013

> I have configured FBA in my web application. I need to use both windows and form authentication. Here when i click sign out it goes to FBA login form. But when i click sign in as different user it shows following exception

Exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' was thrown.
Parameter name: encodedValue

How to overcome this issue..??

thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the exception have a message?

Comment: It shows only following description:  An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Answer (score 0):

According this [source](http://opensourcesharepoint.blogspot.com.br/2013/05/systemargumentexception-when-you-create.html). This issue sometimes happened when the `STSToken` is not working. Try the follow steps:

**1. Check if `STSToken` is working in your farm. Execute the PowerShell
    script. if you get the token back then STS is working.**

```
$farm = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm]::Local 
$webServiceCollection = new-object 
Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebServiceCollection($farm)
foreach ($service in $webServiceCollection)
{
    foreach ($webApp in $service.WebApplications)
    {
        $firstWebApp = $webApp
        #Get the context
        $context = $firstWebApp.GetResponseUri([Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUrlZone]::Default)
        Write-Host "Web Application Context:" $context.AbsoluteUri
        #Call the token generator function
        $token = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurityContext]::SecurityTokenForContext($context)
        Write-Host "Token:" $token.InternalTokenReference
        Write-Host "**************************"
    }
}
```

**2. Check if the FIPS cryptography police is set to disable:**

Go to Local Security Policy > Local Policy > Security Option > System cryptography: Use FIPS...

**3. Once this is done, re-provision the STS using below script:**

> stsadm -o provisionservice -action start -servicetype "Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPSecurityTokenService, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" -servicename SecurityTokenService

After these configurations, your STS should be working correctly.